# how to inc/dec multi user safe in entity framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

What is a clean, safe way to increment or decrement an integer field.

i use sql server 2012 in combination with entityframework 5.x

I look for an equivalent to interlocked increment / decrement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standard way would be to use optimistic concurrency.

Say, you have a simple entity with an integer field `Counter` that you want to increment or decrement:

```cs
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int SomeEntityId { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

You could mark the `Counter` then as a concurrency token. With Fluent API it is:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .Property(s => s.Counter)
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Then you can increment or decrement the `Counter` for example like so:

```cs
public void IncDecCounter(int someEntityId, bool dec)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var someEntity = context.SomeEntities.Find(someEntityId);
        if (someEntity != null)
        {
            bool saveFailed;
            do
            {
                saveFailed = false;

                if (dec)
                    --someEntity.Counter;
                else
                    ++someEntity.Counter;

                try
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
                {
                    saveFailed = true;
                    e.Entries.Single().Reload();
                }
            } while (saveFailed);
        }
    }
}
```

`SaveChanges` will fail with a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` if the value of `Counter` when  the entity has been loaded (with `Find` in this example, could be any other query) differs from the value of `Counter` in the database when the UPDATE statement is executed in the database which would mean that the `Counter` has been modified by another user in the meantime. Technically this is achieved by an extended `WHERE` clause of the generated UPDATE statement that tries to filter not only by the Id but also by the old value of `Counter`, basically something like: `WHERE SomeEntityId = someEntityId AND Counter = oldCounterWhenTheEntityHasBeenLoaded`.

The `catch` block reloads the entity with the current `Counter` value from the database and the next loop tries to increment or decrement the reloaded value again until it succeeds without concurrency violation.

Comment: Thanks. ;-) Hopefully it will be fast enough (-;

Comment: @Slauma, where is this code being called? `modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .Property(s => s.Counter)
    .IsConcurrencyToken();` does your solution still valid in EF6/6.1? And last thing :) - How would you approach this? I didn't get an EF-Wise answer there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825947/creating-object-counters-in-entity-framework-and-sql-server