# Atomic Increment with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a MySQL Server which I access using Entity Framework 4.0. In the database I have a table called **Works** into which some counts. I develop web site with Asp.net. This table acccesable one more user same time. And this situation causes wrong incerement problem.

My code like that:

```
dbEntities myEntity = new dbEntities();

var currentWork = myEntity.works.Where(xXx => xXx.RID == 208).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("Access work");

if (currentWork != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Access is not null");
    currentWork.WordCount += 5;//Default WordCount is 0
    Console.WriteLine("Count changed");
    myEntity.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Save changes");
}
Console.WriteLine("Current Count:" + currentWork.WordCount);
```

If one more than thread access the database same time, only last changes remain.

Current Output:

**t1: Thread One - t2: Thread Two**

> t1: Access work
>
> t2: Access work
>
> t2: Access is not null
>
> t1: Access is not null
>
> t1: Count changed
>
> t2: Count changed
>
> t1: Save changes
>
> t2: Save changes
>
> t1: Current Count: 5
>
> t2: Current Count: 5

Expected Output:

> t1: Access work
>
> t2: Access work
>
> t2: Access is not null
>
> t1: Access is not null
>
> t1: Count changed
>
> t2: Count changed
>
> t1: Save changes
>
> t2: Save changes
>
> t1: Current Count: 5
>
> t2: Current Count: 10

I know why apeear this problem, because this code is not atomic. How can i turn atomic operation?

Comment: I know in MsSql you can have transactions, can you do the same in MySql? Also I know that `SaveChanges()` allows a boolean, but I don't think that will help in this instance.

Comment: can you try this, `lock (currentWork )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Access is not null");
    currentWork.WordCount += 5;//Default WordCount is 0
    Console.WriteLine("Count changed");
    myEntity.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Save changes");
}` it has been a while since I did decent threading

Comment: Oh, and by the way: a good trick. You can put your `where` condition inside your `first or default` and remove the `where` completely.

Comment: @gunr2171 this trick help any performance improve? or trick can help more readable query?

Comment: @Dreamcatcher, I think it makes it more readable, but I'm not sure on performance. I assume it will do the `where` for you. Useful when you have large queries.

Comment: perhaps this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/17972089/1347784

Answer (score 17):

With Entity Framework you can't make this an "atomic" operation. You have the steps:

1. Load entity from database
2. Change counter in memory
3. Save changed entity to database

In between these steps another client can load the entity from the database which still has the old value.

The best way to deal with this situation is to use *optimistic concurrency*. It basically means that the change in step 3 won't be saved if the counter is not the same anymore that it was when you loaded the entity in step 1. Instead you'll get an exception that you can handle by reloading the entity and reapplying the change.

The workflow would look like this:

- In the `Work` entity the `WordCount` property must be marked as a concurrency token (annotations or Fluent API in case of Code-First)
- Load entity from database
- Change counter in memory
- Call `SaveChanges` in a `try-catch` block and catch exceptions of type `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`
- If an exception occurs reload the entity in the `catch` block from the database, apply the change again and call `SaveChanges` again
- Repeat the last step until no exception occurs anymore

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669840/270591) you can find an code example for this procedure (using `DbContext`).

Comment: Can I use this solution Database First approach?

Comment: @Dreamcatcher: Yes. There is an option in the designer for the property settings of `WordCount` to mark it as concurrency token.

Comment: @Slauma - And if the change has to happen without user feedback? For example, a customer orders a product and the inventory needs to be decremented?

Comment: @Sam: In the workflow I described is no user feedback involved or required. Why do you assume that? Maybe I misunderstand your question...

Comment: Well, what do you do when it catches the concurrency exception? Did you keep track of which fields changed and by how much so you can reload the entity and retry?

Comment: @Sam: Ah, I understand. Yes, I think, you must hold the modified properties in another object (a view model or a DTO or a detached entity for example) than the entity you are going to change. If saving fails you can reload the entity and reapply the changes from the other object to the entity again.

Comment: I feel the count should be able to keep adding, not send an error back and try again.

Comment: Pesimistic concurrency using transactions is an option, but even using serializable level sql transactions, you can still run into trouble due to deadlocking: http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/09/entity-framework-and-pessimistic-concurrency/

Comment: There is a gotcha. If when you hit the concurrency exception, If you immediately DbEntityEntry.Reload the entity then wait a holdoff delay then add the 1 and save. The odds are (if load is high) this second attempt will fail too... Its like if you fall over ahead of a herd of elephants, you wont get up until the elephants have all gone... What you need to do is first do the holdoff delay, then do the DbEntityEntry.Reload ... then add 1 to it and save again (so your second attempt is as likely to succeed as all the other elephants)

Answer (score 0):

Next way will work if you hosting your site in single process(it won't work with web farm or web gardsen):

```
   private static readonly Locker = new object();

   void Foo()
   {
          lock(Locker)
          {
                 dbEntities myEntity = new dbEntities();

                 var currentWork = myEntity.works.Where(xXx => xXx.RID == 208).FirstOrDefault();
                 Console.WriteLine("Access work");

                 if (currentWork != null)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Access is not null");
                     currentWork.WordCount += 5;//Default WordCount is 0
                     Console.WriteLine("Count changed");
                     myEntity.SaveChanges();
                     Console.WriteLine("Save changes");
                 }
                 Console.WriteLine("Current Count:" + currentWork.WordCount);
          }
   }
```

What else you can do, is use raw SQL query via ObjectContext:

```
   if (currentWork != null)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Access is not null");
                 myEntity.ExecuteStoredCommand("UPDATE works SET WordCount = WordCount + 5 WHERE RID = @rid", new MySqlParameter("@rid", MySqlDbType.Int32){Value = 208)
                 Console.WriteLine("Count changed");

             }
    var record = myEntity.works.FirstOrDefault(xXx => xXx.RID == 208);
    if(record != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Current Count:" + record .WordCount);
```

Comment: I will use webfarm in the future and lock method might be problem in the future. I thought ExecuteStoreCommand but I would like to write  complete code with EF.