# Creating object counters in Entity Framework and Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

**Note 1:  I REPHRASED THE QUESTION. It now consists of Suppliers and Orders, instead of Cars and Parts.**

**Note 2:  THIS PROBLEM IS HYPOTHETICAL.
My goal is to understand how to create object counters.**

For regulatory requirements, I need TO SEQUENTIALLY NUMBER EACH Order for each of the suppliers.

I'm Using **'Entity Framework`** with Sql Server.

In my **hypothetical** example, I have a `Supplier` class and an `Order` class.

Each supplier has **Orders**. Each order has a product and a quantity. Meaning, it states which product was ordered from the supplier and how many of it.

I need to be able to create counters, like an auto incremented number, to count the orders **FOR EACH supplier**.

For regulatory reasons, each supplier must sequentially number its orders, in the order of creation, and using an integer only.

When we examine an `Order`, We should know by its `OrderCountForSupplier` column, what was its order of creation (a `DateTime / TimeStamp` column is insufficient by the regulatory authorities. They require such a counter).

For simplicity of this question, an order cannot be deleted (it's status can change, but it cannot be deleted).

It's very important for me to have a solution which includes the technical/programming way, not only theoretic way.

I've made a diagram in order to explain my problem in the most clear way possible:

[image]

---

I have a way that might work, and would be glad to hear feedback.

I'm thinking of an external table/tables, to hold the counters. Something like:

```
Supplier Order Counters Table

| SupplierId | OrderCountForSupplier
------------------------
| 54654         | 3
| 78787         | 2
| 99666         | 4
```

Would I need a trigger in order to increment the `OrderCountForSupplier` counter on each insertion, for each supplier?

If not - how can this incremental be done in **a safe way** ? (without for example, two processes in a race condition to get the next counter and increment it, which could eventually result in a duplicate Order Count).

**And another note:**
Can this be done `Entity Framework` wise? if not - a `Sql Server` solution will be respected.

Comment: Are you familiar with "identity" type fields? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Yes - in my example, the `Cars` table, can have an identity auto incremented `int`, which will automatically count 1,2,3... after each insertion. But that doesn't help me to solve the `Parts` table - which is the real problem.

Comment: Your parts table is not correct. Parts table should have `Part_Id` and `PartName` only. There has to be another table called `CarParts` which should have `Car_Id` and `Part_Id` fields.

Comment: @KosalaW - My parts table should hold parts to all cars. But EACH CAR has its OWN parts. There can be 20 parts for `Car A` and 30 parts for `Car B`. But each part is specific and is only related to a single car. If there was such a linkage table called `CarParts` that would have held `Car_Id` and `Part_id` - What would be the `Parts Table` PK? Remember. Each part has to be counted in relation to its specific car.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I've rephrased the question, and used Supplier-Order classes instead of Car-Parts. Now the question is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating some possible approaches (see links at the bottom), I've came out with a very basic solution, with the help of @Vladimir Baranov.

I've ruled out using [SqlServer triggers / Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184749/sql-server-unique-composite-key-of-two-field-with-second-field-auto-increment). They seemed hard to implement in conjunction with Entity Framework, and they seem to me like an Over-Kill in this scenario.

I've also ruled out the [`Optimistic Concurrency` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669383/how-to-inc-dec-multi-user-safe-in-entity-framework-5/15669840#15669840) (using a concurrency token), because in this scenario, the counters cannot be updated simultaneously. They only get updated after a successful insertion to the orders table.

My orders table looks like that. I've added a unique constraint on the `OrderId`, `SupplierId` and `OrderCountForSupplier` trio, so insertion of the same order count for a supplier would fail.

[image]

I've indeed used a counters table, from which I can take the latest counter - for each of the suppliers.

```
Supplier Order Counters Table

| SupplierId | OrderCountForSupplier
------------------------
| 54654         | 3
| 78787         | 2
| 99666         | 4
```

**These are the steps:**

1. Get the current supplier orders counter.
2. Try insert a new order for the supplier, using the current counter + 1.
3. If the insertion goes ok => Increase the orders counter for this supplier, on the supplier counters table.

   If insertion goes wrong, and we get an error stating the has been a violation of the constraint (same order count, which already exists):
   Try 2 more times to get the current counter, and try inserting the order again.

**The Code:**

```
   public class SupplierRepository
   {
        private MyContext _context;
        private Supplier _supplier;

        public SupplierRepository(int supplierId)
        {
            _context = new MyContext();
            _supplier = context.Suppliers.Single(x => x.SupplierId == supplierId);
        }

        // Retrieve the latest counter for a supplier
        public SupplierCounter GetCounter()
        {
            var counterEntity = _context.SupplierCounters.Single(x => x.SupplierId == _supplier.SupplierId);
            return counterEntity;
        }

        // Adding a supplier
        public void AddSupplier(Order order)
        {
            int retries = 3;

            while (retries > 0)
            {
                SupplierCounter currentCounter = GetCounter();
                try
                {
                    // Set the current counter into the order object
                    _order.OrderCountForSupplier = currentCounter.OrderCountForSupplier;
                    _context.Add(order);                        
                    // Success! update the counter (+1) and then break out of the while loop.
                    currentCounter.OrderCountForSupplier += 1;  
                    // I'M CALLING `SAVECHANGES` AFTER ADDING AN ORDER AND INCREASING THE COUNTER, SO THEY WOULD  BE IN THE SAME TRANSACTION. 
                    // THIS WOULD PREVENT A SCENARIO WHERE THE ORDER IS ADDED AND THE COUNTER IS NOT INCREMENTED.
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    break;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Number == 2627) // Violating unique constraint
                    {
                        --retries;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Some useful links:**

- [SQL Server Unique Composite Key of Two Field With Second Field Auto-Increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184749/sql-server-unique-composite-key-of-two-field-with-second-field-auto-increment)
- [Atomic Increment with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971220/atomic-increment-with-entity-framework)
- [how to inc/dec multi user safe in entity framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669383/how-to-inc-dec-multi-user-safe-in-entity-framework-5/15669840#15669840)

Comment: Just generic note. Make sure that you stress test your solution. Start few dozen instances of your application and let them insert few thousand or million orders simultaneously, then check the results. I can't tell from your code, but you should make sure that two data modification steps are performed within the same transaction: inserting new order and increasing the counter. You don't want to let only one of these steps happen without the other.

Comment: Good comment about the transaction... steps 2 and 3 should really be on the same transaction - which i'm pretty sure indeed happens, cause the `SaveChanges` occurs after those two steps run. I'll check this out and update the answer accordingly if necessary.... thanks @VladimirBaranov.

Comment: The `SaveChanges` is now called only after the following two operations are called: the order is added and also the counter is incremented. This forces `EF` to wrap them in the same transaction.

Answer (score 2):

**First answer**, the example in the question has changed after it was written.

You say that is it OK to have gaps in the Part IDs, because "some parts might be deleted along the way".

So, what's the difference between your example:

```
Car      PartID
54654    1
54654    2
54654    3
78787    1
78787    2
99666    1
99666    2
99666    5
99666    7
```

And this variant:

```
Car      PartID
54654    1
54654    2
54654    3
78787    4
78787    5
99666    6
99666    7
99666    8
99666    9
```

In the second variant each part has some ID that is unique for each car (it is also globally unique as well, but it doesn't matter). In the second variant `PartID` specifies the order in which parts were inserted into the table, same as in the first variant.

So, I'd use a simple `IDENTITY` column:

**Parts**

```
PartID int IDENTITY NOT NULL (PRIMARY KEY)
CarLicenseNum int NOT NULL (FOREIGN KEY)
PartName varchar(255)
```

### Update for Supplier-Order example

The most important bit in the updated question is **"regulatory reasons"**. It answers the question why would you want to do such unnatural thing. "Regulatory" and efficiency are often opposite.

Essentially, it means that you have to use [serializable transaction isolation level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173763.aspx) when inserting a new row and calculating the next number in the sequence. It will hurt concurrency/throughput, but it will guarantee consistency and "be safe" in multi-user environment.

I don't know how to do it in Entity Framework, it should be possible. But, again, for "regulatory reasons" I'd put this logic in the stored procedure in the DB and make sure that ordinary users don't have write access to the `Orders` table directly, but have rights only to execute this dedicated stored procedure. You can replicate the logic of this stored procedure in the EF code, but the database itself will be open to changes done through other applications, which may not follow the regulatory requirements.

You can implement it using the separate table, which stores the latest sequence number for each supplier, or you can read the last maximum sequence number on the fly. If each supplier has only few orders, then this separate table with latest values of counters would be comparable to `Orders` table and you would not gain much. In any case, having a proper index is the key. Getting the latest counter value would be one seek in the index.

Here is an example of stored procedure without using an extra table.

Make sure that `Orders` table has unique index on `(SupplierId, OrderCountForSupplier)`. In fact, you must have this index even if you are using an extra table to enforce the constraint.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddOrder]
    @ParamSupplierID int, 
    @ParamProductSerial varchar(10),
    @ParamQuantity int,
    @NewOrderID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @VarMaxCounter int;

        SELECT TOP(1) @VarMaxCounter = OrderCountForSupplier
        FROM dbo.Orders
        WHERE SupplierID = @ParamSupplierID
        ORDER BY OrderCountForSupplier DESC;

        SET @VarMaxCounter = ISNULL(@VarMaxCounter, 0) + 1;

        INSERT INTO dbo.Orders
            (SupplierID
            ,OrderCountForSupplier
            ,ProductSerial
            ,Quantity)
        VALUES
            (@ParamSupplierID
            ,@VarMaxCounter
            ,@ParamProductSerial
            ,@ParamQuantity);

        SET @NewOrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- TODO: handle the error
        SET @NewOrderID = 0;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

END
GO
```

Comment: I can't. The demand is to have a counter for each Car's Parts. In the real world it's a regulatory demand of the authorities, to count orders for each supplier. And it has to be sequentially counted.

Comment: I've rephrased the question, and used Supplier-Order classes instead of Car-Parts. I'd be glad if your answer would refer to my rephrased question. Thanks.

Comment: @ilans, I updated the answer and showed how I'd approach meeting "regulatory requirements".

Comment: At last, a really detailed answer that seems to touch the pain. I think that's the direction i need to go. Just another question - I you did have to make a separate table with the counters, how would you prevent two parallel insertions to take the same counter? how would you lock access to a single process?

Comment: I've decided to solve this the EF way, without any Stored Procedure nor Transactions... I will bounty this question tomorrow just in case. If no answer - I will publish mine.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without transaction. If you use a separate table with counters you still should wrap the process into a transaction with serializable isolation level. Serializable isolation level does this "lock access to a single process". If you do it in your EF application, not at the DB level, it means that only your EF application would adhere to regulatory requirements and any other application can bypass the required logic. It is quite common that several different applications work with the same database. That's why it is important to configure constraints at the DB level.

Comment: Actually, it **is** possible without serializable transaction. You can use optimistic approach. Just don't lock anything explicitly and try to generate the next value. If your insert fails due to unique constraint violation, you handle the error and retry until it succeeds. This kind of question has been asked many times, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184749/sql-server-unique-composite-key-of-two-field-with-second-field-auto-increment

Comment: Exactly what I planne

Comment: Hi @Vladimir. Can you please see my updated answer and give me your thoughts? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: it is not OK to change your question entirely! Delete this question and create a new one. Having said that ...

Answer of the current question:

Answers to hypothetical questions are just oppinion based and/or too broad (there is actually a flag for this - `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`)!

My answer to the current question is: I do not see any benefit (or advantage or use) of the `OrderCountForSupplier` in the **database**! Creating such counter in the database makes *adding* and *maintenance* (in a multi-threaded environment) very complicated and error-prone.

I think the problem can be solved more easily with the help of EF (move the creation of the counters in the code) and a different design of the database:

- in order to allow concurrent adding of Orders, create two columns - a `GUID` as the `Order`-PrimaryKey and a `CreationDate` of type `DateTime`. Filling those two columns from multiple threads is not a problem
- when retrieving all `Orders` for a specific `SupplierId`, sort the result list in ascending order by `CreationDate`
- when iterating over the result list using (for example) a for-loop, then the counter is the desired sequential counter
- as an alternative to the EF solution, the creation of the sequential counter can stay in SQL - create a view or stored procedure for the `Order` items and use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to create the artificial sequential count, after grouping the items over `SupplierId` and sorting on `CreationDate`

Reading the database from multiple threads (and creating the counter in every thread) is again not a problem any more.

---

Answer of the first question:

You are almost there. You need to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data model a little bit more. This is a common scenario in which you want to minimize redundancy of the data and at the same time still maintain a meaningful relation (without the use of triggers).

One possible solution would be to create a `Car_has_Part`-Table in order to represent the relation between a `Car` and a `Part` entity:

```
| Car_has_Part |
----------------
| PartId       |
| CarId        |
```

The primary key of the `Car_has_Part` table is a **composite primary key** consisting of `CarId + PartId` which is unique and at the same time you avoid data duplication.

In your example in the `Parts` table the `Doors` part is repeated for every `Car`. Using this *intermediate* table the data is not duplicated and you have a proper relation.

Your new data model could look like this:

```
| Car  |    | Car_has_Part |    | Part   |
-------     ----------------    ----------
|CarId |    | PartId       |    | PartId |
|Model |    |              |    | Descr  |
| etc. |    | CarId        |    | etc.   |
```

This model allow resp. covers the specified requirements:

> I need to be able to create a counter, like an auto incremented
>   number, to count the parts for each car. Car 1, could have parts 1, 2,
>   3... and Car 2 would also have parts 1, 2, 5, 7... (some parts might be deleted along the way).

Select all `PartId`'s from the `Car_has_Part` table over `CarId`.

> Each part HAS to be counted separately for its related car. That's the
>   base requirement.

Same as above (without data duplication like in your example). Adding resp. removing a relation or modifying a part name has also become easier - you need to update only one row in the `Parts` table and the change is reflected for every car.

About the triggers question - you can only create a trigger with EF (using code first approach). Regarding execution - triggers are always executed in the database and EF can't control trigger execution (you can certainly enable/disable trigger using [raw SQL queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx), but if I understand your question correctly this is not what you want).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve my problem... In my example each part, like a door, is not related to the other. Each door is of a different manufacturer and has a different lifetime etc...

Comment: IMO it does. Extend the `A_has_B` table (resp. the composite key) in order to match your exact criteria - PartId is related to CarId and ManifacturerId (or whatever makes your relation unique). You will still avoid replication and allow easier data manipulation. If you have two different doors, then you will have two different PartId's.

Comment: But if each part is unique, how will you solution normalize my data? I can't see how your solution kills replication here. And more importantly, I NEED to hold an ID for each part that belongs to a series of parts for a car. You didn't solve this...

Comment: Well if really *each* part is unique, then you do not need normalization at all, so why creating two tables at all and not only one (car + part data)? In your example you have duplicated/redundant data/relations - CarId (1,2,3) and PartId (1,2).

Comment: I will end this discussion in this: If I have a car and you have a car, we have different cars and different parts.

Comment: `I NEED to hold an ID for each part that belongs to a series of parts for a car` - what does this exactly mean? How does this reflect/match tha stated requirements in your question?

Comment: You are wrong... I want to use the car class / table throughout my project. And need a single parts table.

Comment: I suggest you to make examples, draw a picture of the model and fill the tables adn create the relations using pen and paper and see which model does fit your requirements best.

Comment: Even if I go along with your suggestion - you did not specify how you would maintain DIFFERENT counters to each SERIES of parts. Each Car has its own such series.

Comment: Then your question resp. your requirements is/are not clear enough. What is a `series of parts`? My solution does cover the two specified questions - count each part separately for each car.

Comment: I've rephrased the question... if you have a proposition for changing the title of the question you are more than welcome to suggest :) Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105486/discussion-between-pasty-and-ilans).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105508/discussion-between-ilans-and-pasty).

Comment: I've rephrased the question, and used Supplier-Order classes instead of Car-Parts. I'd be glad if your answer would refer to my rephrased question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real world example. That's why you are struggling. For an example, A real world parts entity is lot more complicated than that. A real world part will have a ManufacturerId (BMW, Audi etc), PartNumber(B4-773284-YT), VehicleModelId (AUDI A4 etc), Description, ManufacturerYear so on and so forth. Usually when it comes to parts entities, we use a concatanated primary key on ManufacturerId and PartNumber.

Same with your car table. It's not a real world example too. Car entity should have a VIN number, which is unique. When you say each part is specific, you are not talking about Part entity. You are talking about PartInventory entity. PartInventory has a unique serial number (barcode) for each part. So every single part can be identified uniquely. When you attach a part to a vehicle, you are not just attaching a Part, you are actually attaching a PartInventory item, which is recognizable by a unique serial number.

Once the partInventory item is attached to a vehicle, it becomes a fitted part item of the vehicle. Which means the part gets transferred to `VehicleParts` table.

Unfortunately I see a lot of gaps in your vehicle industry domain knowledge. We develop systems to address real world problems. When you try to address hypothetical problems, you run in to this kind of issues. That leads to wasting lot of other peoples time who are trying to help you out.

Comment: I don't pretend to give a real world example. It's just an example. The goal is know how to create counters. I added 2nd note to the question to clarify that.

Comment: Ok. Based on what you just said, You need another table called `MyPartCounter`. It will have just one field and a row called `LastPartNumber`. Everytime you add a new Part, use the available number in that field as the `PartNumber`. Once the part is added, increment that number by one.

Comment: I've rephrased the question, and used Supplier-Order classes instead of Car-Parts. I'd be glad if your answer would refer to my rephrased question. Thanks.

Comment: By looking at your `OrdersTable` I can understand what you are trying to do. In general we call this kind of numbering, _Line Numbers_ or _Line Ids_. But it's perfectly ok to use some other name. So the most important part that you need to understand is that the Line Numbers should not be incremented via the database. You have to have some logic in your front end to calculate line numbers. So in your database `OrderCountForSupplier` is simply an integer. You have to have a concatenated primary key on `orderId, SupplierId, OrderCountForSupplier` fields.

Comment: I can't seem to find any relation to front end here... this could as well be an under surface service. And no - of course it HAS to be incremented in the DB....  Anyway, yes - I could have used a composite key instead of OrderId. I didn't do this - so the spotlight won't be on the composite key, as was when I used Cars-Parts. But still... i can't get a complete answer...

Comment: It does not matter whether the order is created by your own front end or some kind of a web service or a automated bot. Whoever tries to create an order, will have to respect your primary key. If you are developing your own front end, you will have to handle that by your self. In your business logic layer, you need to have some validation rules to validate if the line number starts with 1 and increments sequentially.

Comment: What's the best practice to make such incrementation? Would I have to use DB triggers? See the end of my question referring to this issue.

Comment: I don't recommend anyone to write business rules in triggers. You have to write them in your business logic layer.

Comment: So you want to write your business rule in triggers? Is that the answer that you want?

Comment: No. I don't rule out any solution. But I need a full answer here.

Comment: What did you mean by "Full" answer? What part did I miss?

Comment: I need a full answer to my question. I still haven't got a complete answer to my question. Not a comment...

Comment: Good luck. SO may not be the right place for you. :)

Comment: It might be true.. I will put a bounty tomorrow.