# Sync two server instances against one database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, synchronization, microservices

I'm using C# and the .NET framework, and I have a monolithic server which is connected to a database. I'm uploading the server to AWS and initialize two instances of it.

The problem is in writing to the database.

I'm using Entity Framework and the following is the problem code:

```
using (var db = new CordioContext())
{
    Student student = db.Students.Where(s => s.Id == studentId).FirstOrDefault();
    student.coursesCount++;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I only have one instance of the server, I can put a lock on the student Id and avoid two threads trying to update the same entity at the same time.

What can I do when I have two different instances which are connected to the same database?

How it's done in microservices architecture?

I have read a little bit about transactions but I'm not sure this will solve my problem.

The example code above is just to explain the problem. In my code, I'm changing many more fields and transfer everything to a SQL query instead of EF code first is very ugly.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the scenario that database transactions should be used for.

Comment: So if I would wrap my code with using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                { }  and at the end I will put dbContextTransaction.Commit(); It will prevent the collision?

Comment: You should really consider *optimistic concurrency* to detect concurrent changes, without the need of locks (and transactions): https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @iakobski The transaction doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma It mainly talks about versioning and It doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: Please, take your time to *understand* how optimistic concurrency works, before discarding it as a *bad solution*. Here you are some more tips on how to increment a counter atomically using this approach: [how to inc/dec multi user safe in entity framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669383/how-to-inc-dec-multi-user-safe-in-entity-framework-5/15669840#15669840) [Atomic Increment with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976819/3670737)

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Those examples solve my problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Do you know how can I prevent from creating two entries? If two servers check for the existence of an entry and then both of them creates a new one. I truly don't feel like the solution is good enough.

Comment: A simple unique index will suffice. Please note that creating a new entity (if it does not exist) is a different problem than what you are asking in the question (which will only address the update of an existing entity).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Thank you so much for the fast response! I know this is not what I asked in the main question.

Comment: `db.Students.Where(s => s.Id == studentId).FirstOrDefault()` doesn't help you. You should use `db.Students.Single(s => s.Id == studentId)`

Answer (score 1):

"updating the same entity at the same time. " - This 'at the same time' is very rare to happen, even if it does since you are already using entity framework, use versioning of the entities. "update XXX set (....) where XXX.version_id=`old_version_id`+1;
This will take care of parallel updates. The DB writes are serialized.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I don't want to save few versions for each entity in db.

Comment: Not new rows. Version will be a stored a column information.